# Adjusting background image over @page margins for print view

Tags: css, printing, background

I'm not expert in CSS, so bear with me in advance if my question may seem silly to experts.

I'm trying to find out a way to make the product pages of my website look nicer when printed out.

To this purpose, I'm trying to add a background image which has a logo in the header, a footer and a message in the left side margin.
In order for these background elements to show, I've set the size and margins of the page in the custom.css file of my template (I'm using Joomla CMS). This is the code I used (which correctly does what I meant, that is, making the content appear within the set margins):

```
@page {
  /* set size of printed page */
  size:210mm 297mm;      
  margin-top:25mm;
  margin-bottom: 12mm;
  margin-right: 3mm;
  margin-left: 8mm;
}
```

Then, in the .css file of the page I added this code:

```
body { 
  background-color: white !important;
  background-image: url('/images/print/sfondo-pdf_v2.jpg') !important;
  background-position: 0px 0px !important;             
  background-size: 100% auto !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-y !important;
  background-origin: border-box !important;
  background-clip: border-box !important;
  background-attachment: scroll !important;             
}
```

The problem is, the background is not contained in the total size of the page (i.e. 210mm 297mm), but it is instead contained within the margins previously set.

I would like to know what I should do in order for *only* the background to ignore the @page margins.

I hope I have clearly explained my point and thank you all in advance!